# Angular2 - read environment variable from PM2

Tags: node.js, angular, environment-variables, systemjs, pm2

My `Angular2` app is running inside `NodeJS` app (something like MEAN app), which is started by `PM2`. I have set an environment variable in my PM2 configuration which I can access from the NodeJS app with `process.env.MY_VAR`. I was wondering if it is possible (and how) to access this variable from the Angular2 app? May be I can pass it as a parameter to the `SystemJS`, but I'm not really sure exactly how I have to do it. Any ideas?